# How to capture the values from Get Response Body - Robot framework

Tags: json, python-2.7, robotframework

**Output from Response Body**

```
{"data":[{"id”:122,"name”:”Test 1“,”description”:”TEST 1 Test 2 …..}]},{"id”:123,"name”:”DYNAMO”……}]},{"id”:126,”name”:”T DYNAMO”……
```

---

```
*** Keywords ***    
Capture The Data Ids 
@{ids}=     Create List    122  123  126  167  190   
${header}    Create Dictionary    Authoriztion...   
${resp}      Get Response    httpsbin    /data    

${t_ids}=       Get Json Value    ${resp.content}    /data/0/id
```

**Problem**

I have created a list of above ids in the test case and I need to compare the created data against the id returned in the response body.
t_ids returns 122and when 0 is replaced by 1, returns 123

Rather than capturing individual id, is it possible to put them in for loop?

```
:FOR    ${i}  IN          ${ids}
\    ${the_id=       Get Json Value    ${resp.content}    /data/${i}/id ?
```

I tried this and failed.

What is the possible solution to compare the ids from the response data against the created list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to what you want, but it is always good to know what kind of data structure your variable contains. In the below example loading a json file replaces the received answer in `${resp.content}`. To my knowledge this is a string, which is also what `Get File` returns.

The example is split into the json file and the robot file.

**so_json.json**

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":122,
            "name": "Test 1",
            "description": "TEST 1 Test 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "DYNAMO"
        },
        {
            "id": 126,
            "name": "T DYNAMO"
        }
        ]
 }
```

**so_robot.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library    OperatingSystem    
Library    Collections    


*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${json_string}  Get File    so_json.json
    ${json_object}  Parse Json    ${json_string}
    :FOR  ${item}    IN    @{json_object['data']}
    \    Log To Console    ${item['id']}
```

Which in turn gives the following result:

```
==============================================================================
Robot - Example                                                             
==============================================================================
Robot - Example.SO JSON                                                     
==============================================================================
TC                                                                    122
123
126
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Robot - Example.SO JSON                                               | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Robot - Example                                                       | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: @Kootstra, this worked !!!. Thank you so much. Was able to extract the data/id from response and compare against the test data. Some fine tuning required and will post the solution soon. Thank you once again

Comment: If this is indeed the solution you seek, mark this response as the answer so that others will know this at a glance.

Comment: //Test file
 ${data_file_string}        Get File        <filename>.txt
        ${data_file_obj}          Parse Json      ${data_file_string}
 :FOR    ${I}    IN    @{data_file_obj['data']}
        \       Append To List          ${list_1}     ${i['ids’]} 

        Sort List    ${list_1}
     
 ${resp}         Get Request     http   /<url>    
        ${resp_data}=     Parse Json  ${resp.content}
        :FOR    ${i}    IN    @{resp_data['data']}
        \       Append To List          ${list_2}     ${i['ids’]} 
 Sort List    ${list_2}
 List Should Be Equal   ${list_1}    ${list_2}